# Margin-top won't move individual elements

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm trying to make a comment box that is horizontal with the name box, because the text box was fixed on the top. When I tried to apply margin-top on the text area and form, it moves the name box and the whole entire profile down with it. Is there a way to move the text area down, without affecting anything else. Here is my code:

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
}
p.name {
 font-family: "Roboto";
 margin-top: 90px;
 margin-left: 50px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 border: 1px solid black;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 20px 70px;
 font-size: 25px;
}
div.info {
 margin-left: 50px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 20px 13.5px 20px;
 border-top: none;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
div.date {
 margin-left: 50px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-top: none;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0px 17px 0px;
 text-align: center;
}
form {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 100px;
}
textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  font-size: 16px;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="profile.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>
<body>
<p class="name">henWrek</p>
<form>
<label for="fname">Profile Comments:</label>
<br>
<textarea>Enter your comment here...</textarea>
</form>
<br>
<div class="info">
<img src="default.jpg" height="200" width="210">
</div>
<br>
<div class="date">
<p>Joined: 11/1/2018</p>
<p>Last Online: 11/9/2018 3:21PM</p>
<p>Post Count: 2</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to put a position to the label tag and this tag have a relative position and you can change top and right to move when you want.

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
}
p.name {
 font-family: "Roboto";
 margin-top: 90px;
 margin-left: 50px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 border: 1px solid black;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 20px 70px;
 font-size: 25px;
}
  
div.info {
 margin-left: 50px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 padding: 20px 13.5px 20px;
 border-top: none;
 display: inline-block;
 margin-bottom: 0;
}
label{
    position:relative;
    top:50px;
    right:100px;
}
div.date {
 margin-left: 50px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-top: none;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0px 17px 0px;
 text-align: center;
}
form {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 100px;
}
textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  font-size: 16px;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="profile.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>
<body>
<p class="name">henWrek</p>
<form>
<label class="label-prueba" for="fname"> Profile <br> Comments:</label>
<br>
<textarea>Enter your comment here...</textarea>
</form>
<br>
<div class="info">
<img src="default.jpg" height="200" width="210">
</div>
<br>
<div class="date">
<p>Joined: 11/1/2018</p>
<p>Last Online: 11/9/2018 3:21PM</p>
<p>Post Count: 2</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

try *margin-top* with a negative value, for instance: `margin-top: -2px;`

Answer (score 0):

I have seen your code and found your problem, my suggestion is kindly add two property to your `.textarea` class and that is `position:relative` and `top` as per your requirement.

```
textarea{
   position:relative;
   top:100px;
}
```

Comment: I used this instead of the top comment, but both worked!